# Could having to add the extra 4-5 days to change the status of nidah to zaav and not allowing the original 7 day nida be like adding to a mitzva?

Tags: niddah

As I understand, the additional 4-5 days which are added as a humra in case the lady is a zaav is a barrier for protecting from miscalculating and being over nida. My question is whether this stringent enforcement is actually permissible considering that the original law that had been practiced for centuries was that of 7 days. If one is interested in being careful and doing the nida days only, shouldn't that be taught and help out those who would like to do it?
There is a concept of bringing a korban if you have been a nazir since you were ascetic and abstained from wine/grapes etc... a product that is otherwise permissible. My arguement is whether being forced to keep these extra days and causing this ascetic behavior is also a sin for those who wish to keep the 7 days only?
I hope that I am not insulting anyone by asking these questions. Thank you.

Comment: AA: your closing off my question just further supports my disdain for lack of open dialogue on halacha. perhaps I will continue to look for another venue to ask my questions. I assume you must be a moderator in order to do that? In any case, I will be glad to read anyone's comments.

Comment: He closed it because it has been addressed in the question he linked. In short, actual count of 7 days is impossible to determine with certainty, which is why the rabbis added days. It was once possible. We no longer have the knowledge to perform the simple count without potentially transgressing a torah prohibition, though. They are making a protective fence around torah law, which is their responsibilty. Your question is addressed more thoroughhly in the link, though. Hope your disdain is lessened. Welcome!

Comment: I don't think the linked question adequately addresses the question, which is about the 72 hours from the last relations that have to elapse before you can start counting the 7 clean days. That is a biblical law, derived by drasha from a paseuk, and applies biblically to niddah as well as zavah.

Comment: The two chumrot that the Rema holds that make the halacha be 5 days from when the woman's period starts are a chumrot that are addressed by the other question. The best advice I can give you is to find a rav who knows this subject well, who can explain the sources of the various halachot involved. I don't really know the details well enough to explain them myself, and there are few English books that explain in enough detail to correct all of the misconceptions packed into this question.